# Error starting Mosquitto MQTT broker using mymosquitto.conf

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to run Mosquitto with TLS support, I followed [this](http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/PaoloPatierno/entryid/366/mqtt-over-ssl-tls-with-the-m2mqtt-library-and-the-mosquitto-broker) to generate certificates and configuration.
When i try to start Mosquitto with the command

```
 mosquitto –c mosquitto_m2mqtt.conf –v
```

this is the result:

[image]

can someone help me?

Comment: Edit the question to include the full text of your config file, it appears you have some values in there that are wrong

Comment: Yes, please edit the question and add the right filename in the command line as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `-c` is not typed in ascii charset. The error complains about `'^uc'` not `'-c'`.

What have you found out?